# Beveling a plane that has been extrude 90 degrees

Tags: bevel

[image]I followed a tutorial for setting up a scene with light but got stucked at first point.
I first create a plane and then I extrude it 90 degrees. Then I want to bevel the sharp edge to be round. I select the edge in edit mode and apply bevel. But i only works on one of the two planes. The tutorial was using 2.79 and I am using 2.8. Is there any reason why this not working?

My projectfile: [image]

Comment: Hello :). Please, share your file https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/. It might be just double edges, but just to be sure.

Comment: Are you able to do this in 2.8? I mean this is no rocket science. I tried with new planes as well. And it is only one object. Not two edges either.

Comment: It works just fine in 2.8. It could be a bug, that's why it's useful to have someone else replicate the issue with your file. :)

Comment: Thanks, it is uploaded now. Look origin post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a rather simple reason:
Your object's *scale* is messed up.

Your object has uneven scale, so the bevel is applied 400x times more on one side, than on the other.
Fix it by going to *Object->Apply->Scale.*
Then the *bevel tool* will work as you need it.

*Fix your scale*
[image]

*Then it works as it should*
[image]

Comment: Wow amazing. How did you found out that? It works like a dream now. Thank You.

Comment: Having correct scale is kind of important in 3d modeling - so checking it becomes a second nature :). Many tools depend on correct scale to work properly, so remeber to check it once in a while.

Comment: You can now mark the answer as accepted (the green checkmark) for others with the same problem :). Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

are you using Ctrl+B or the Bevel Modifier? could you add a screenshot? it would be very helpful

edit:
I think your vertices might be disconnected, have you tried to start again with a new plane?

Check your right bottom info, without the bevel you should only have 2 faces and 6 vertices.

Comment: I am using ctrl B or click in the menu to the left side. I can bevel a box so it works on other objects when selecting the edge. Added image where you see what happens.